# Problemas con el plugin DataTables

Tags: php, sql, datatables

me explico estoy haciendo un crud de momento funciona todo bien segui una guia porque la verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento y la guia no tenia el plugin de dataTables que pienso que es importante en un CRUD pero las agrego y se daña el modal pero no aparecen las tablas  y la verdad ya no se donde mas ponerlas 
este es el codigo sin poner el plugin

```
<?php

require('../php/seguridad.php');
require_once('../php/Conexion.php');
$conn = Conectar();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>.::Cerdos::.</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscerdo/ajaxcer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/administrador/">Deseas Ir al Inicio?</a> 

 </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>.::Cerdos::.</h1>


        <button type="button" Onclick='Modal();' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Nuevo
        </button>

      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">.::Lista de Cerdos::.</div>
        <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>


            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Cerdo</th>
              <th>Chapeta</th>
              <th>Raza</th>
              <th>Genero</th>
              <th>Modulo</th>
              <th>Corral</th>
         <th></th>

   <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>



            <?php
              $sql = "SELECT * 
                  FROM cerdo cer 
                  INNER JOIN raza raz ON raz.id_raza=cer.id_raza 
                  INNER JOIN genero gen ON gen.id_genero=cer.id_genero 
                  INNER JOIN corral cor ON cor.id_corral=cer.id_corral 
                  INNER JOIN modulo mdu ON mdu.id_modulo=cor.id_modulo 
                  ORDER BY cerdo";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            foreach($rows as $row){
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php print($row->id_cerdo); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row->cerdo); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row->chapeta); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row->raza); ?></td>
                  <td><?php print($row->genero); ?></td>
                  <td><?php print($row->modulo); ?></td>           
                <td><?php print($row->corral); ?></td>
                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Seleccione</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                      <li><a onclick="Eliminar('<?php print($row->id_cerdo); ?>');">Eliminar</a></li>
                      <li><a onclick="Editar('<?php print($row->id_cerdo); ?>','<?php print($row->cerdo); ?>','<?php print($row->chapeta); ?>','<?php print($row->raza); ?>','<?php print($row->genero); ?>','<?php print($row->modulo); ?>','<?php print($row->corral); ?>');">Actualizar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
            }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Cerdo</h4>
            </div>

            <form role="form" action="" name="frmClientes" onsubmit="Registrar(idP,accion); return false">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cerdo</label>
                  <input name="cerdo" class="form-control" required>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Chapeta</label>
                  <input name="chapeta" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lll">Raza</label>
                 <select  id="lll" name="raza">
                  <?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM raza ORDER BY raza";
$stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  ?>
<option value ="<?php print($row->id_raza);?>"><?php print($row->raza);?></option>

<?php

}

?>
</select>
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="lll">Genero</label>
                 <select  id="lll" name="genero">
         <?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM genero ORDER BY genero";
$stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>
<option value ="<?php print($row->id_genero);?>"><?php print($row->genero);?></option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">                

          <label for="lll">Modulo</label>
                 <select  id="lll" name="modulo">
         <?php


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM modulo ORDER BY modulo";

$stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  ?>
<option value ="<?php print($row->id_modulo);?>"><?php print($row->descripcion);?>"><?php print($row->modulo);?></option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>
 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lll">Corral</label>
                 <select  id="lll" name="corral">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM corral ORDER BY corral";
$stmt =$conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  ?>
<option value ="<?php print($row->id_corral);?>"><?php print($row->corral);?></option>

<?php
}
?>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrar
                </button>

              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>x</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Modal(){
    Nuevo();
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    }

    var accion;
    var idP;
    function Nuevo(){
      accion = 'N';
      document.frmClientes.cerdo.value = "";
      document.frmClientes.chapeta.value = "";
      document.frmClientes.raza.value = "";
      document.frmClientes.genero.value = "";
      document.frmClientes.modulo.value = "";
      document.frmClientes.corral.value = "";
      $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
    function Editar(id, cerdo, chapeta, raza, genero, modulo, corral ){
      accion = 'E';
      idP = id;
      alert(cerdo,chapeta,raza,genero,modulo,corral);
      document.frmClientes.cerdo.value = cerdo;
      document.frmClientes.chapeta.value = chapeta;
      document.frmClientes.raza.value = raza;
      document.frmClientes.genero.value = genero;
      document.frmClientes.modulo.value = modulo;
      document.frmClientes.corral.value = corral;
      $('#modal').modal('show');
    }


    </script>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve tratando de reproducir algún problema entre ambas librerías y no me ha ido nada mal. Te puedo aconsejar algunas cosas:

- Asegúrate de importar la tanto el CSS como el JS de jQuery.dataTables después de importar jQuery, ya que jQuery.dataTables toma funciones de jQuery y si se importa antes no cumplirá con sus funciones correctamente.

```html
  
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

- Agrega tus scripts y styles en la sección  (antes del  del documento.
- Asegúrate de inicializar el dataTable:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: [0],
                    orderData: [0, 1]
                }, {
                    targets: [1],
                    orderData: [1, 0]
                }, {
                    targets: [4],
                    orderData: [4, 0]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

*Agrega el CSS de Bootstrap.

Espero te haya ayudado, un abrazo.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu ayuda pero no me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está demasiado complejo por la interpolación de html y php como para debuggear. Lo que te recomiendo es que hagas todas tus consultas a la BBDD en un comienzo e imprimas el resultado como JSON, de manera que de ahí hacia abajo todo se haga con variables JS.

Por ejemplo, en vez de:

```
      $sql = "SELECT * 
              FROM cerdo cer 
              INNER JOIN raza raz ON raz.id_raza=cer.id_raza 
              INNER JOIN genero gen ON gen.id_genero=cer.id_genero 
              INNER JOIN corral cor ON cor.id_corral=cer.id_corral 
              INNER JOIN modulo mdu ON mdu.id_modulo=cor.id_modulo 
              ORDER BY cerdo";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach($rows as $row){
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php print($row->id_cerdo); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row->cerdo); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row->chapeta); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row->raza); ?></td>
              <td><?php print($row->genero); ?></td>
              <td><?php print($row->modulo); ?></td>           
            <td><?php print($row->corral); ?></td>
            ...
         </tr>
         <?php } ?>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Hacer:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo 'var cerdos = JSON.parse('. json_encode($rows) .')';
```

Y tendrás la variable cerdos definida como un objeto javascript, de manera que después podrás llenar la tabla haciendo:

```
  cerdos.forEach(function (cerdo) {
    var tr = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
    jQuery('<td>' + cerdo.id_cerdo + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
    jQuery('<td>' + cerdo.cerdo + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
    jQuery('<td>' + cerdo.chapeta + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
    jQuery('<td>' + cerdo.raza + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
    var editar = $('<button type="button"  class="editar btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</button>');

    editar.data('cerdo', cerdo);
    btns = jQuery('<td></td>');
    btns.append(editar)
      .appendTo(tr);
    $('#table').find('tbody').append(tr);
  });
  $('#table').DataTable();
```

Si te fijas, el botón para editar un cerdo no tiene todas las características de éste inline, sino que le añadí un data-attribute con el objeto "cerdo" de manera que después puedes hacer:

```
  $('.editar').on('click', function () {
    var cerdo = $(this).data('cerdo');
    document.frmClientes.id_cerdo.value = cerdo.id_cerdo;
    document.frmClientes.cerdo.value = cerdo.cerdo;
    document.frmClientes.chapeta.value = cerdo.chapeta;
    document.frmClientes.raza.value = cerdo.raza;
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo, claro que usé los datos de https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html que tienen empleados en vez de cerdos, pero para editar y listar se ve bastante claro.

```js
 var empleados = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "office": "Tokyo"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "office": "San Francisco"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "office": "Edinburgh"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "office": "Tokyo"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "office": "New York"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "office": "San Francisco"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "office": "Tokyo"
    }];

    var puestos = ["Accountant", "Junior Technical Author", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Integration Specialist", "Sales Assistant", "Javascript Developer", "Software Engineer", "Office Manager", "Support Lead", "Regional Director", "Senior Marketing Designer", "Marketing Designer", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "Systems Administrator", "Personnel Lead", "Development Lead", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "Pre-Sales Support", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "Developer", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "Regional Marketing"];
    var oficinas = ["Tokyo", "San Francisco", "Edinburgh", "New York", "London", "Sidney", "Singapore"];



    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


      empleados.forEach(function(empleado) {
        var tr = jQuery('<tr></tr>');
        jQuery('<td>' + empleado.id + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
        jQuery('<td>' + empleado.name + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
        jQuery('<td>' + empleado.position + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
        jQuery('<td>' + empleado.office + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
        var editar = $('<button type="button"  class="editar btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</button>');
        editar.data('empleado',empleado);
        btns = jQuery('<td></td>');
        btns.append(editar)
        .appendTo(tr);
        $('#table').find('tbody').append(tr);
      });
      $('#table').DataTable();
      
      puestos.forEach(function(puesto) {
        $('#puestos').append('<option value"'+puesto+'">'+puesto+'</option>');
      });
      
      oficinas.forEach(function(oficina) {
        $('#oficinas').append('<option value"'+oficina+'">'+oficina+'</option>');
      });

      $('.editar').on('click',function() {
        var empleado=$(this).data('empleado');
          console.log()
          document.frmClientes.id.value = empleado.id;
          document.frmClientes.nombre.value = empleado.name;
          document.frmClientes.oficina.value = empleado.office;
          document.frmClientes.puesto.value = empleado.position;
        $('#modal').modal('show');
      });
    });
```

```css
    #table td {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h3>.::Empleados::.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      
      <div class="panel-heading">.::Lista de Empleados::.</div>
      <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Puesto</th>
            <th>Oficina</th>
            <th width="100px">Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar empleado</h4>
          </div>

          <form role="form" action="" name="frmClientes" onsubmit="Registrar(idP,accion); return false">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Id</label>
                <input name="id" id="id" class="form-control" required>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="puestos">Puesto</label>
                <select id="puestos" name="puesto">
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="oficinas">Oficina</label>
                <select id="oficinas" name="oficina">
                </select>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrar
              </button>

            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>x</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu colaboracion puedes guiarme un poco la verdad soy algo noob y no sabria como hacerlo

Comment: Qué parte en especial te parece confusa? Lo que preguntas es muy amplio, guiarte un poco puede ser virtualmente algo que dure toda la vida :D

Comment: @user90058 Si lo que te ha puesto ffflabs te parece poca guía, es que es verdad que eres un poco noob, y lo que necesitas es estudiar y aprender. Va a ser imposible guiarte si no tienes una base mínima, en vez de guiarte lo que va a tener que hacer es enseñarte, y eso efectivamente puede convertirse en algo amplísimo.